# Open port 93 on Google Compute?

Tags: port, google-compute-engine

I can't open port 93 on Google Compute although I did allow that port in the firewall of Console Google Cloud.
Only ports 80 and 3389 are activities!

Comment: is your instance listening on that port? `netstat -an | grep 93`

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any error messages or a way to test ? 
You can try the following :

1. from your local machine, outside GCE, run `$ telnet IP 93` and `$ nmap -p 93 IP`
2. from the GCE instance, check if your port is open `$ telnet localhost 93`

This can give you a better idea if indeed the port is open and accepting connections.

Comment: I'm using Windows Server 2008, I can't use telnet command in cmd? how to run?

Comment: Use http://www.adminkit.net/telnet.aspx to telnet. Can you ssh into your GCE instance from Developers Console > Comput engine > VM Instances > SSH ? If so, run $ telnet localhost 93 , to check if the port is open and accepting incoming connections.